# How to avoid implicit include statements in Rhapsody code generation

Tags: include, code-generation, rhapsody

I'm creating code for interfaces specified in IBM Rational Rhapsody. Rhapsody implicitly generates include statements for other data types used in my interfaces. But I would like to have more control over the include statements, so I specify them explicitly as text elements in the source artifacts of the component. Therefore I would like to prevent Rhapsody from generating the include statements itself. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the properties that let Rhapsody produce the required output: `GenerateImplicitDependencies` for several elements and `GenerateDeclarationDependency` for Type elements. Disabling these will avoid the generation of implicit include statements.

Answer (score 0):

If this can be done, it is mostly likely with Properties. In the feature box click on properties and filter by 'include' to see some likely candidates. Not all of the properties have descriptions of what exactly they do so good luck.

EDIT:

I spent some time looking through the properties as well an could not find any to get what you want. It seems likely you cannot do this with the basic version of Rhapsody. IBM does license an add-on to customize the code generation, called Rules Composer (I think); this would almost certainly allow you to customize the includes but at quite a cost.

There are two other possible approaches. Depending on how you are customizing the include statements you may be able to write a simple shell script, perhaps using *sed*, and then just run that script to update your code every time Rhapsody generates it.

The other approach would be to use the Rhapsody API to create a plugin/tool that iterates through all the interfaces and changes the source artifacts accordingly. I have not tried this method myself but I know my coworkers have used the API to do similar things.

Comment: I did this already but I didn't find a property which does what I need (maybe the right one is called differently, so I missed it).